# Solr - How to boost a field in Solr? Not getting the correct query

Tags: solr, field

I'm using Solr 1.4.1. I need to boost a field. My schema.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->

<schema name="default" version="1.1">
  <types>
    <fieldtype name="string"  class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

    <!-- Numeric field types that manipulate the value into
     a string value that isn't human-readable in its internal form,
     but with a lexicographic ordering the same as the numeric ordering,
     so that range queries work correctly. -->
    <fieldType name="sint" class="solr.SortableIntField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="slong" class="solr.SortableLongField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="sfloat" class="solr.SortableFloatField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="sdouble" class="solr.SortableDoubleField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.DateField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="ngram" class="solr.TextField" >
      <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="1">
      <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
  </types>

  <fields>   
    <!-- general -->
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true"/>
    <field name="django_ct" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="django_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

    <dynamicField name="*_i"  type="sint"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_l"  type="slong"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_f"  type="sfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_d"  type="sdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_dt" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

    <field name="location_ad" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="location_ad_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="date_inserted" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="zone_ad_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="country_ad" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="job_description" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="zone_ad" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="job_title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
  </fields>

  <!-- field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness. -->
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
  <!-- field for the QueryParser to use when an explicit fieldname is absent -->
  <defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
  <!-- SolrQueryParser configuration: defaultOperator="AND|OR" -->
  <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND" />
</schema>
```

I need to do the following: I need to give more importance to the "job_title" field. If for example I'm searching for the word "programmer" I need to show in the first place the results that have "programmer" in the "job_title" field ordered by date and then the results that have the word "programmer" in the "job_description" field. It is better to do an example, my english is not the best in the world ;)

I have this data:

```
job_title                | job_description                    | date_inserted
programmer               | job for IT guys                    | 10-Nov-2011
IT Python                | for python programmer              | 12-Nov-2011
PHP programmer           | PHP programming                    | 08-Nov-2011
```

I need for example when searching for the word "programmer" to give more importance to the field "job_title" but show also in the results the documents that have the word "programmer" in the "job_description" field. I need also to give importance to the "date_inserted" field, so that the results appears like this:

```
job_title                | job_description                    | date_inserted
programmer               | job for IT guys                    | 10-Nov-2011
PHP programmer           | PHP programming                    | 08-Nov-2011
IT Python                | for python programmer              | 12-Nov-2011
```

I'm doing a query like this:

```
/?facet=on&sort=date_inserted+desc&fl=*+score&start=0&q=programmer&bf=job_title:programmer^1.50&facet.field=location_ad_exact&facet.field=zone_ad_exact&fq=django_ct:(myapp.jobsadstext)&rows=20
```

But the result of this query is not what I need.

Can someone give me a clue about the track I need to follow to achieve the result?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have to use DisMax query parser ‘defType=dismax‘) to use boosting.
2. Use qf parameter for field query (in your sample you are using bf - boost function)

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#qf_.28Query_Fields.29

Comment: Thank you for the reply Matej. I have done this query:"/?facet=on&sort=date_inserted+desc&fl=*+score&start=0&q=arquiteto&qf=job_title^1.50+job_description^1&facet.field=location_ad_exact&facet.field=zone_ad_exact&fq=django_ct:(emp1001br.jobsadstext)&rows=20" unfortunately the result is the same. I'm doing something wrong? Best Regards,

Comment: You can see verbose output with `&debugQuery=true` - use view source in your browser for better formatting.

Comment: Add `&defType=dismax` to use DisMax query parser. You have to use DisMax if you want field boosting.

Comment: great! Now I see the score. My problem now is about the order by. If I order by "score" I lost the "sort=date_inserted". the query is like this: "?facet=on&sort=date_inserted+desc&fl=*+score&start=0&q=arquiteto&qf=job_title^100+job_description^1&defType=dismax&facet.field=location_ad_exact&facet.field=zone_ad_exact&fq=django_ct:(emp1001br.jobsadstext)&rows=20". How can I order by "score" and "date_inserted"?

Comment: You have to add function query to boost on date. See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents for details. Sorry for missing this from the beginning.